# Pycharm выдаёт ошибку Unused import statement

Tags: python, pycharm

Говорит, что импорт не используется, я с ним категорически не согласен. При нажатии на ошибку вариатна игнорировать нет В настройках тоже не нашёл пункта проверки на эту ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я бы попробовал убрать те импорты, которые у вас через "звездочку" (переделать в более "узкие" импорты), возможно из этих модулей у вас другие модули импортируются. Вообще, это не ошибки, а предупреждения.

Comment: @insolor спасибо, помогло